# Include MongoDB Image in returned object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I store small images in MongoDB.
I successfully [retrieved an Image](http://coding.paulandkana.com/?p=12) with no problems.
When i tried to include the image inside an object I failed ending up with an image represented as an array that i can not convert to base64 data.
My Question:
Is it possible to send an image data which is included inside an object with several fields?
If I refer to the link, instead of:

```
res.send(doc.img.data);
```

I would like to do:

```
res.send(doc);
```

**EDIT:**
Adding my working code:

```
    company.file.data = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.files.file.path), 'base64').toString('base64');
    company.file.contentType = req.files.file.type;

    // Data is not delivered as string but as an array
    company.save(function(err, company) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        res.contentType(company.file.contentType);
        return res.send(company.file.data);
    })
```

I woule like to send the whole company object:

```
    return res.send(company);
```

But then i get the company.file.data represented as an  array on the client side...

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you're using to save/retrieve the image? Are you trying to convert the binary image into a base64 encoded image?

Comment: Yes, isnt it what i suppose to do?

Comment: No comments for a while.       
For future users I'll just add that i didnt find a solution for that, so for the meantime i send an image in a dedicated API call.